Kafka and Elastic search Certs Manager on GCP
We have a requirememt whereby we are deploying our clusters on GCP along with deploying Kakfa clusters, brokers, topics and partition on Google Cloud Platform.
Now we need to have a monitoring service on GCP which gets kicked off when the Kafka certs are going to expire and it renews them with minimal manual intervention.
We also intend to integrate Elastic Search on GCP which will also entail monitoring and renewing the certs by some certs manager.
Please advise on how can we achieve this functionality.
Thanks.
